# SOS2 constraints along an index of a multiple indexed variable

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to enforce SOS2 constraints on a variable indexed over 2 sets, adding the constraints over a loop. I came up with something like the following lines, but it is not working:

```
model = ConcreteModel()

model.I = RangeSet(0,I)
model.J = RangeSet(0,J)
model.K = RangeSet(0,K)

model.x = Var(model.I,model.J,model.k,domain=NonNegativeReals)

for j in model.J
  for k in model.K
    exec(f'model.SOS2x_{j}_{k} = SOSConstraint(model.x[:,j,k], sos = 2)')
```

Can anybody please help me in what I am trying to achieve above? Thank you

In general, it is not clear to me how to impose the SOS constraint a unique index.